# Android custom Drawable vs custom View

Tags: android

I wanted to know what's the difference between creating a custom Drawable like in the Shelves project: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/ to creating a custom View?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Drawble` only response for the draw operations, while view response for the draw and user interface like touch events and turning off screen and more.

View can contain many `Drawbles`.